# How to minimize PostgreSQL distribution size

Tags: postgresql

I am considering to use PostgreSQL as a internal database of my Windows Application. It looks fast and good enough for the repository.

The size of binary distribution is about 180MB. 
Has anyone thought about minimizing the size of it for the much more small distribution by removing unnecessary files?
My requirement is just to use PostgreSQL as a internal repository, so I just load text data into the database and the Application queries to display the data.

If you could let me know the file lists I could remove, the that would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/garethflowers/postgresql-portable or even SQLite instead of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Oh.It looks great!. I have used SQLite but for allowing remote connection by application client, I should switch it to PostgreSQL. Do you know this portable one allows remote connection as well?

Comment: I would think so but I don't know for sure. You should check it out or send Gareth Flowers a tweet.

Comment: It seems that a Windows batch program controls PostgreSQL server and it should be always popped up. I need to have Application starts/stops PostgreSQL so I guess it won't be easy to handle it and binary files are not small. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a batch file to start Postgres. The Postgres server is controlled through `pg_ctl`, you can run that directly from within your application. But you need to make sure it's properly shut down. Registering it as a windows service (`pg_ctl register -N servicename`) is probably the safest thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For v9.3, unzipped looks as below. For sure you could remove "doc, pgAdmin" directories and probably go through "bin" directory and remove those .exe files that are not required (i.e. pgAdmin.exe, stackbuilder.exe, etc.)

```
 27M    ./bin
 15M    ./doc
8.8M    ./include
 18M    ./lib
 12M    ./pgAdmin III
 13M    ./share
780K    ./StackBuilder
 59M    ./symbols
154M    .
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to remove those ones. The thing is whether I could remove files in the 'symbols' directory. Thank you.

Comment: @Sigularity: You can remove the directories `symbols`, `include` and `StackBuilder` (and doc and pgAdmin as Kamchybek as already stated)

Comment: Very good then. I was thinking about removing "symbols" which occupies a lot. Thank you so much.